# Elm 0.19 Maybe.withDefault

Tags: string, int, elm, option-type

I have read the documentation, but i still don't understand how to Maybe.withDefault in my code. Because from a String.toInt I get Maybe Int, I cant use a + sign to add the values I try to convert into Integers. This is Elm 0.19. How can I fix this?

```
import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, button, div, text)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)


main =
  Browser.sandbox { init = init, update = update, view = view }


-- MODEL

type alias Model = {mainNum : String, curNum : String}

init : Model
init =
  {
      mainNum = ""
      ,curNum = ""
  }

-- UPDATE

type Msg = AddNum String | Add | Clear 

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  case msg of
    AddNum number ->
        {model | curNum = model.curNum ++ number}

    Add ->
        {model | curNum = String.fromInt ((String.toInt model.curNum) + 
(String.toInt model.mainNum))}

    Clear ->
        init



-- VIEW

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ div [] [ text  model.curNum]
    , button [ onClick (AddNum "1" )] [ text "1" ]
    , button [ onClick (AddNum "2" )] [ text "2" ]
    , button [ onClick (AddNum "3" )] [ text "3" ]
    , div [] []
    , button [ onClick (AddNum "4" )] [ text "4" ]
    , button [ onClick (AddNum "5" )] [ text "5" ]
    , button [ onClick (AddNum "6" )] [ text "6" ]
    , div [] []
    , button [ onClick (AddNum "7" )] [ text "7" ]
    , button [ onClick (AddNum "8" )] [ text "8" ]
    , button [ onClick (AddNum "9" )] [ text "9" ]
    , div [] []
    , button [ onClick (AddNum "0" )] [ text "0" ]
    , button [ onClick Clear] [ text "Clear" ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
withDefault : a -> Maybe a -> a
```

This is a function received 2 params (the last one is the returned value).

If `a` is an `Int` then we have:

```
withDefault : Int -> Maybe Int -> Int

-- if `a` is a `Float` then we have
withDefault : Float -> Maybe Float -> Float

-- in general, if `a` is an `X` then we have
withDefault : X -> Maybe X -> X
```

The **1st param** is the one that will be returned once the **2nd param** is `Nothing`.

So if the **2nd param** isn't `Nothing` then the function will return the value inside **2nd param**.

so basic example:

```
-- hard-code 2nd param
withDefault 10 (Just 20) -- this function call results 20
withDefault 10 Nothing -- this function call results 10
```

advanced ones:

```
-- 2nd param is Nothing
withDefault 10 (String.toInt "abc") -- this function call results 10

-- 2nd param is not Nothing
withDefault 10 (String.toInt "123") -- this function call results 123
```

into your code:

```
Add ->
    let
        cur : Int
        cur =
            Maybe.withDefault 0 (String.toInt model.curNum)

        main : Int
        main =
            Maybe.withDefault 0 (String.toInt model.mainNum)
     in
     { model | curNum = String.fromInt (cur + main) }
```

As you can see, the `Maybe.withDefault` makes sure you always receive `Int` for your `add returned Int` calculation.

Without it, you will always receive `Maybe Int` and the add of `Maybe Int` will always returns `Maybe Int`.

Note:
My code above is only for `Maybe.withDefault` usage explanation, not for production code

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your question:

1. `String.fromInt` returns `Maybe Int`, it means that the value can be either `Just Int` or `Nothing`
2. You cannot just add e.g. `Just 1` and `Nothing` together or even `Just 1` and `Just 2`
3. You need to extract the number from `Just 1` somehow or specify default value if it's `Nothing` (e.g. 0).
4. This is where `Maybe.withDefault` comes in handy. It can extract `Int` from any `Maybe Int` (doesn't matter if it's `Nothing` or `Just`). It takes 2 parameters:

   - first is the default value that is used when the second parameter is `Nothing`
   - second is the actual `Maybe` value

So in your code you can use it like this:

```
{model 
  | curNum = 
      String.fromInt <|
        (Maybe.withDefault 0 <| String.toInt model.curNum) 
        + (Maybe.withDefault 0 <| String.toInt model.mainNum)
}
```

Having said all this you could just save all the trouble by using `Int`s in your model and `String.fromInt` in your views.

Answer (score 1):

You do need a string with `text` but your onClicks can work with messages that take Ints.  i.e.

```
button [ onClick (AddNum 7)] [ text "7" ]
```

I suggest you change your model to work with ints too, and then you won't have to do any conversion from/to strings at all

Comment: I have changed the buttons to work with ints, and my AddNum code to this: {model | curNum = String.toInt ((String.fromInt model.curNum) ++ (String.fromInt number))} But I still need to convert an Int to a String. Same error

Comment: I use the AddNum function to create a number, not add one

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the error by creating a function that converts Maybe Int -> Int:

```
checkInt : Maybe Int -> Int
checkInt x = case x of
    Just y -> y
    Nothing -> 0
```